# How to download data to b.csv that like a.csv format from gae localhost server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, format

My a.csv is:

```
001,哈哈大学
002,拉拉大学
003,啊啊啊大学
004,文网文大学
005,卡卡卡大学
006,请求权大学
007,凤飞飞大学
```

And my str_loader.py is:

```
class College(db.Model):
    cid = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class CollegeLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'College',
                                   [
                                    ('cid', str),
                                    ('name', lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf8')),
                                   ])

loaders = [CollegeLoader]
```

And I use this code to update data to localhost server:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=zjm1126 --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --filename=upload/a.csv --kind=College --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api
```

I want to test download data to b.csv that like a.csv format,

So do this:

```
appcfg.py download_data  --application=zjm1126 --kind=College  --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api --filename=b.csv
```

How to download data to `b.csv` that like `a.csv` format.

I have added this to `str_loader.py`:

```
class CollegeExporter2(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'College',
                                   [
                                    ('cid', str),
                                    ('name', lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf8')),
                                   ])
exporters = [CollegeExporter2]
```

I use this code to run:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --application=zjm1126 --kind=College  --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api --filename=b.csv
```

But, it show error:

```
D:\zjm_demo\app>appcfg.py download_data --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --app
lication=zjm1126 --kind=College  --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api --filena
me=b.csv
Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20100619.120030
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 68, in <module
>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 64, in run_fil
e
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2757, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2748, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 1763, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2619, in __call__
    return method()
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2451, in PerformDownload
    run_fn(args)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2368, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 4014, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 3837, in _PerformBulkload
    LoadConfig(config_file)
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 3553, in LoadConfig
    Exporter.RegisterExporter(cls())
  File "upload/str_loader.py", line 57, in __init__
    ('name', lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf8')),
  File "d:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 2786, in __init__
    for name, fn, default in properties:
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

And when I run:

```
print repr(open('b.csv', 'rb').read())'
```

I am getting:

```
'SQLite format 3\x00\x04\x00\x01\x01\x00@  \x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x03\xfc\x00\x03\x02\xd5\x00\x03f\x03\xcf\x02\xd5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x81\x0e\x03\x07\x17GG\x01\x81\x1btablebulkloader_database_signaturebulkloader_database_signature\x04CREATE TABLE bulkloader_database_signature (\n      value TEXT not null)g\x01\x07\x17\x19\x19\x01\x81)tableresultresult\x02CREATE TABLE result (\nid BLOB primary key,\nvalue BLOB not null,\nsort_key BLOB)+\x02\x06\x17?\x19\x01\x00indexsqlite_autoindex_result_1result\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\r\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x94\x00\x03\x85\x03\n\x02\x8c\x02\x0e\x01\x90\x01\x12\x00\x94\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00|\x07\x05H\x81>\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000742j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe6\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03007r\x1b\x1a\x04name \x00*\x11\x1a\x0f\xe5\x87\xa4\xe9\xa3\x9e\xe9\xa3\x9e\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe6\x05\x0c|\x06\x05H\x81>\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000741j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe5\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03006r\x1b\x1a\x04name \x00*\x11\x1a\x0f\xe8\xaf\xb7\xe6\xb1\x82\xe6\x9d\x83\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe5\x05\x0c|\x05\x05H\x81>\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000740j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe4\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03005r\x1b\x1a\x04name \x00*\x11\x1a\x0f\xe5\x8d\xa1\xe5\x8d\xa1\xe5\x8d\xa1\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe4\x05\x0c|\x04\x05H\x81>\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000739j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe3\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03004r\x1b\x1a\x04name \x00*\x11\x1a\x0f\xe6\x96\x87\xe7\xbd\x91\xe6\x96\x87\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe3\x05\x0c|\x03\x05H\x81>\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000738j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe2\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03003r\x1b\x1a\x04name \x00*\x11\x1a\x0f\xe5\x95\x8a\xe5\x95\x8a\xe5\x95\x8a\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe2\x05\x0cy\x02\x05H\x818\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000737j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe1\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03002r\x18\x1a\x04name \x00*\x0e\x1a\x0c\xe6\x8b\x89\xe6\x8b\x89\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe1\x05\x0cy\x01\x05H\x818\r:College\x00\x0000000000000000000736j\x19j\x07zjm1126r\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe0\x05\x0cr\x0e\x1a\x03cid \x00*\x05\x1a\x03001r\x18\x1a\x04name \x00*\x0e\x1a\x0c\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\xad\xa6\x82\x01\x0e\x0b\x12\x07College\x18\xe0\x05\x0c\n\x00\x00\x00\x07\x03\x0b\x00\x03\xdd\x03\xba\x03\x97\x03t\x03Q\x03.\x03\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000742\x07"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000741\x06"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000740\x05"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000739\x04"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000738\x03"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000737\x02"\x03H\x01:College\x00\x0000000000000000000736\x01\r\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03!\x00\x03!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x81\\\x01\x03\x83?\n  app_id: zjm1126\n  url: http://localhost:8100/remote_api\n  kind: College\n  download: False\n  map: False\n  dump: True\n  restore: False\n  progress_db: bulkloader-progress-20100619.121020.sql3\n  has_header: False\n  \n  '
```

```
class CollegeExporter2(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'College',
                                   [
                                    ('cid', str,None),
                                    ('name', lambda x:x.encode('utf8'),None),
                                   ],)
exporters = [CollegeExporter2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/using-the-python-bulk-exporter-tool-with-a-java-application/ , first add the following to your str_loader.py:

```
class CollegeExporter(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'College',
                                   [
                                    ('cid', str, None),
                                    ('name', lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf8'), None),
                                   ])
exporters = [CollegeExporter]
```

Next, run:

`appcfg.py update zjm1126`

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=upload/str_loader.py --application=zjm1126 --kind=College  --url=http://localhost:8100/remote_api --filename=b.csv
```

Of course you probably ultimately want to create a separate file for download vs. upload, but you get the idea.

Comment: Argh! It looks like the tuples in bulkloader.Exporter.__init__ require a third (default) argument. Try the slightly changed code above...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that  you dump the contents of b.csv by issuing the following command at your shell prompt

```
python -c"print repr(open('b.csv', 'rb').read())"
```

That way we can see what is actually in the file.

HOWEVER It looks very much like an SQLite3 database -- perhaps you need to explore what options the appcfg.py script has for choosing an output file format.

Answer (score -2):

by loading the data into an sqlite db and then dumping that via the python csv module.

Comment: -1 It looks like he already has an SQLite3 DB, *AND* the Python csv module doesn't read SQLite3 DBs!

Comment: don't be ridiculous, of course there's a step in reading the data and writing it through CSV but it's less than 10 lines of code. I'm not doing it for him, just pointing out it isn't difficult. I dump databases to CSV all the time.

Comment: If you can write something that can dump _this_ sqlite DB to meaningful CSV in 10 lines of code, I'll be amazed. The database he's got is a data dump of his App Engine datastore, stored in encoded protocol buffer format. The better option is to do what gilesc demonstrates, and actually use the built in CSV dumper.